# Efficient way to declare and access a huge array

Tags: c++

I am writing a code for which I need to declare an array of around 200 indexes. Now to search a specific index I at least need to travel the array for a defined time or until desired value is achieved - hence at times I might need to travel 200 times if needed - for 200 value row.

This is exactly I wish to ignore so I landed coding it below way:

```
enum Index{ salary, age };

static const Datas Mydata [] = 
{
[Index::one] = {"hello", function_call_ptr_1, function_call_ptr_2}, 
[Index::two] = "hekllo1",  function_call_ptr_1, function_call_ptr_2}
};
```

Hence in my code I can directly seek it like below:

```
Mydata [Index::age]
```

Assuming that access to above structure is to be done inside a function - hence the function should receive Index value as argument to itself. But still what if arguments passed was wrong like:

```
age = 0;
fun(age);
```

Is there a better way to access Mydata  so that its desired row can easily be accessed without any flaw?

Comment: Note that C++ doesn't have initialization designators. The syntax `[index] = value` is only valid in C, not in C++.

Comment: There is a wonderful video of Herb Sutter explaining how inserting and looking up random values is faster using a `std::vector` (even with reallocation) than any other standard container.  They stop testing at 500,000 elements with the different still getting larger

Comment: And what you seem to be looking for is [`std::map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) or more likely [`std::unordered_map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map).

Comment: seems like you are looking for std::map or std::set or std::pair

Comment: Found it 0:46 into the video: https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2014/2-661

Comment: Just use a [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).